# createBitmap error in Froyo but not on ICS

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception

My code runs without any errors on ICS but in Froyo it gives me a runtime `NullPointerException` on the `Bitmap.createBitmap()` call (line 7 in code below.) What can be causing it?

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.title_bg_tile);
int width = view.getWidth();
int intrinsicHeight = bd.getIntrinsicHeight();
Rect bounds = new Rect(0,0,width,intrinsicHeight);
bd.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
bd.setBounds(bounds);

Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width(),bounds.height(),bd.getBitmap().getConfig()); //<----Error on this line

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
bd.draw(canvas);
```

EDIT: My Logcat during crash on Froyo:

```
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.tab.fragment.TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity$1.onGlobalLayout(TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java:95)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:549)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1094)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-23 10:50:14.900: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the document says http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getConfig() >> "If the bitmap's internal config is in one of the public formats, return that config, otherwise return null." so there is a chance to be null. I think you can go for a hard coded cofig from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

Comment: try to set a static value for your H & W and check if it works, so yes you know where your nullPointerException come from. otherwise its your instance of the bitmap thats null

Comment: In the end I never could come up with a solution. And got another way of achieving what I was trying to do.